# Question on inverse limits

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, general-topology, category-theory, limits-colimits

> **1.7. Remark.** The inverse limit of an inverse system of non-empty sets might be empty as the following example
>   shows: Let $I:=\mathbb{N}$ and $X_n:=\mathbb{N}$ for every
>   $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Let $\theta_{n\leftarrow
> > n+1}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N},k\mapsto k+1$.  Now assume
>   $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is contained in the inverse limit.  Then
>   $x_{n+1}=x_n-1$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ yielding a contradiction.

[Reference](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/paravici/files/essay.pdf)

My question is: How is the inverse limit the empty set? I have computed that the inverse limit is the set of all constant sequences of $\mathbb N$.

Could someone explain this?  The author commented on it but I was unable to understand it.

Comment: How did you compute? That would help us help you. I agree with the author. It is very important here that $X_n = \mathbb N$ instead of $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant sequences $(c_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ of $\Bbb{N}$ are not in the inverse limit because they do not satisfy
$$\theta_{n\leftarrow n+1}(c_{n+1})=c_n,$$
for *any* $n$ at all. To see that the inverse limit is empty, suppose toward a contradiction that $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ is in the inverse limit. Then it satisfies $x_n=\theta_{n\leftarrow n+1}(x_{n+1})$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$, and by induction
$$x_n=\theta_{n\leftarrow n+m}(x_{n+m})=x_{n+m}+m,$$
holds for all $,\in\Bbb{N}$. Taking $n=1$ and $m=x_1$ we get
$$x_1=\theta_{1\leftarrow\ 1+x_1}(x_{1+x_1})=x_{1+x_1}+1+x_1,$$
a contradiction.

Colloquially speaking, the fact that $x_{n+1}=x_n-1$ means that the sequence is strictly decreasing. An infinite sequence in $\Bbb{N}$ cannot be strictly decreasing, so there is no sequence in the inverse limit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it well.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that as the indices increase the numbers decrease by $1$. Eventually we will have to hit a negative number, but $\mathbb N$ does not contain any of those.

Comment: Could you please be more specific in providing some steps of what you said?

Comment: @Ahmed the condition imposed by the maps in the system is that $x_{n+1}=x_n-1$ for all $n$. Expanding the recurrence gives us $x_n=x_0-n$. Then $x_{x_0+1}=-1\notin \mathbb N$, so no sequence of natural numbers can satisfy the conditions.