# Questions on inverse limits

Tags: abstract-algebra, limits-colimits

Let $(S_n,\pi_n)$ be an inverse sequence, where $S_n=\mathbb N$ for each $n$. If each $\pi_n$ is identity, then the inverse limit, $\varprojlim S_n$, is (bijective to) $\mathbb N$.

My first question is: how $\varprojlim S_n\simeq\mathbb N$ ($\simeq$ means is bijective). My approach, let $s\in\varprojlim S_n$. Now $s=(s_0,s_1,s_2,...)$, and $s_1=s_0, s_2=s_1, ...$. Therefore $\forall n\in\mathbb N, s_0=s_n$. This means that all $s\in\varprojlim S_n$ are constant sequences. If I am correct, how this can be identified with $\mathbb N$. IF NOT, please provide some steps lead to the solution.

My second question is: Consider this example given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840600/question-on-inverse-limits/1840616). What will be the $\varprojlim S_n$ if each $X_n=\mathbb Z$??

all ideas are welcome.

Comment: Use the universal property of diagrams to compute limits. Also, it is fairly common in mathematics to identify constant sequences on a set $X$ with the elements of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the classical explicit set-theoretic description of the inverse limit.

- **About the first question**. You argument is correct: as you noted the inverse limit $\varprojlim S_n$ is the sub-set of $\prod S_n$ made of all the sequences which are constant. Then the $0$-th canonical projection $\pi_0 \colon \prod S_n \to S_0=\mathbb N$ is a bijection, whose inverse is given by the mapping $$\pi_0^{-1} \colon \mathbb N \to \prod S_n$$ that sends every $s \in \mathbb N$ into the corresponding constant sequence.
- **About the second question**. If I've understood correctly, your considering the inverse diagram 
  $$\mathbb Z \stackrel{-+1}{\longleftarrow}\dots \longleftarrow
     \mathbb Z \stackrel{-+1}{\longleftarrow} \mathbb Z
     \stackrel{-+1}{\longleftarrow} \mathbb Z \longleftarrow \dots $$
  whose inverse limit is the set 
  $$\varprojlim S_n=\{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \in \prod_{n \in \mathbb N}\mathbb Z \colon x_n = x_{n+1}+1\}$$ 
  which can be rewritten as
  $$\{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \in \prod_{n \in \mathbb N}\mathbb Z \colon x_{n+1}=x_n - 1 \}\ .$$
  Even in this case the projection $\pi_0 \colon \varprojlim S_n \to \mathbb Z$ defined by the equation $\pi_0((x_n))=x_0$ is a bijection. The inverse is given by the mapping 
  $$\pi_0^{-1} \colon \mathbb Z \to \varprojlim S_n $$
  $$\pi_0^{-1}(s)=(s-n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$$
  indeed is not hard to see that $(x_n)_n=(s-n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is an element of $\varprojlim S_n$, by trivial calculations we can see that $$x_{n+1}=s-(n+1)=(s-n)-1=x_n-1\ ,$$
  and again by calculations one can see that $\pi_0^{-1}\circ\pi_0=\text{id}_{\varprojlim S_n}$ and $\pi_0 \circ \pi_0^{-1}=\text{id}_{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @ZikoSarbi what do you mean? could you add a little more details?

Comment: Suppose that $f_{n+1n}:S_{n+1}\mapsto S_n$ are our bonding maps which are defined by  $f_{n+1n}(x)=x+1$. Doesn't this mean that $x_{n+1}=x_n+1$. But you have written it like $x_n = x_{n+1}+1$ in the inverse limit $$\varprojlim S_n=\{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \in \prod_{n \in \mathbb N}\mathbb Z \colon x_n = x_{n+1}+1\}.$$ I must have problem with this.

Comment: I think it could be a notation problem: the point is that in my notation $f_n \colon S_{n+1} \to S_n$ (my indexes are shifted). 
Next we can observe that by definition $f_n(x_{n+1})=x_{n+1}+1$ and so since we require $x_n=f_n(x_{n+1})$ we have that $x_n=x_{n+1}+1$. Does this help?

Comment: Excellent. I got it well. Your answer was very explicit. Thanks

Comment: @ZikoSarbi you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, the bijection will be
$$
(s, s, s, \dots) \mapsto s.
$$
For the second one, I think the answer should be that $\varprojlim S_n \cong \mathbb Z$. To see this, note that any *compatible* sequence is determined by its first element, and this can be an arbitrary element of $\mathbb Z$. So in this case the bijection (in the other direction) will be
$$
z \mapsto (z, z-1, z-2, \dots).
$$

Comment: Could you please be able to explain the 2nd one little bit better? and how to define this bijection $z \mapsto (z, z-1, z-2, \dots).$